# Packing an infinite sequence of disks

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, closed-form, packing-problem, combinatorial-geometry

Let $a > 1$ and $Q(a)$ denote the supremum of values of $q$ such that a countably infinite collection of disks, whose areas form an infinitely decreasing geometric progression with the start value $1$ and the common ratio $q$ (i.e. $\{1,\ q,\ q^2,\ q^3,\ \dots\}$), can be packed within a circle of area $a$.

Apparently, $0 < Q(a) < 1$ and is monotonically increasing.

- Can we find a closed form expression for $Q(a)$? Or at least, some non-trivial bounds?
- Can we find the exact value of $Q(2)$, for example?
- What properties of the function $Q(a)$ can be proved? Is it continuous, smooth, analytic?
- What's its asymptotic behavior for $a\to1$ and $a\to\infty$?

Comment: An obvious bound is $(1 - (1/\sqrt{a}))^{2} \leq Q(a) \leq 1-(1/a)$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Part I - Exact result for small $a$**

> Let $\rho_c \approx 0.75487766624669$ be the unique real root of the cubic equation $\rho^3 + \rho^2 - 1 = 0$. When $a \le a_c = (1 + \rho_c)^2 \approx 3.079595623491439$, 
>   $$Q(a) = (\sqrt{a}-1)^2$$

Let $\rho = \sqrt{q}$. Given any two circles with area $1$ and $q$, their diameter will be $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ and $\frac{2\rho}{\sqrt{\pi}}$. Any geometric figure containing both of them must have a diameter $\ge \frac{2(1+\rho)}{\sqrt{\pi}}$.
In particular, if a circle of area $a$ contains both of them, we will have
$$2\sqrt{\frac{a}{\pi}} \ge \frac{2(1+\rho)}{\sqrt{\pi}}\quad\iff\quad
a \ge (1+\rho)^2 \quad\iff\quad q \le (\sqrt{a}-1)^2$$

This gives us an upper bound for all $a$:

$$Q(a) \le (\sqrt{a}-1)^2$$

When $a \le a_c = (1 + \rho_c)^2$, we can actually pack a sequence of circles of area $\rho^{2k}, k = 0, 1, \ldots$ where $\rho = \sqrt{a}-1$ inside a circle of area $a$. 
This leads to a lower bound

$$Q(a) \ge (\sqrt{a}-1)^2$$

and above assertion will follow. To see how this is done.

1. We start with a circle of radius 
   $\sqrt{\frac{a}{\pi}} = \frac{1+\rho}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ at the origin. 
   Let us call it $C_a$.
2. We then place two new circles, $C_b$ and $C_0$, with 
   radius $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ and $\frac{\rho}{\sqrt{\pi}}$
   inside $C_a$. We position them in such a way so that their centers
   lying on the $x$-axis and $C_a, C_b$ and $C_0$ are kissing each other.
3. There are now two slots inside $C_a$, one above and one below the $x$-axis
   where we can place a $4^{th}$ circle kissing $C_a, C_b$ and $C_0$.
   We place a circle kissing $C_a, C_b, C_0$ in the upper slot and call it $C_1$.
   We place another circle kissing $C_a, C_b, C_0$ in the lower slot and call it
   $C_{-1}$.
4. Now above $C_1$, there is a slot inside $C_a$ we can place a $4^{th}$ circle kissing 
   $C_a, C_b$ and $C_1$. We place such a circle there and call it $C_{2}$.
5. Now above $C_2$, there is a slot inside $C_a$ we can place a $4^{th}$ circle kissing
   $C_a, C_b$ and $C_2$. We place such a circle there and call it $C_{3}$.

We can repeat these steps repeatedly. If we do the same thing to those slots below
$x$-axis, we will ultimately obtain a sequences of circles $\ldots, C_{-2}, C_{-1}, C_0, C_1, C_2, \ldots$. such that for every integer $k$, the two quadruples of circles 
$( C_a, C_b, C_{k}, C_{k+1})$ and $( C_a, C_b, C_{k}, C_{k-1})$ are kissing among themselves.

This sequence of circles form part of an [Apollonian gasket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_gasket) (see figure at end of Part I). Let $\frac{\rho_k}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ be the radius of $C_k$. If we apply [Descartes' four circle theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_theorem) to the pair of quadruples of circles for each $k$, we find $\lambda = \frac{1}{\rho_{k+1}}$ and $\frac{1}{\rho_{k-1}}$ are the two roots of a quadratic equation

$$\left( \lambda + 1 + \frac{1}{\rho_k} - \frac{1}{1+\rho}\right)^2
= 2 \left(\lambda^2 + 1 + \frac{1}{\rho_k^2} + \frac{1}{(1+\rho)^2}\right)$$

This leads to
$$\frac{1}{\rho_{k+1}} + \frac{1}{\rho_{k-1}} = 2 \left(1 + \frac{1}{\rho_k} - \frac{1}{1+\rho}\right)
\quad\iff\quad 
\frac{1}{\rho_{k+1}} - \frac{2}{\rho_k} + \frac{1}{\rho_{k-1}} = \frac{2\rho}{1+\rho}
$$

The RHS is an inhomogeneous recurrence relation in $\frac{1}{\rho_k}$ with constant terms.
Since the associated polynomial has a double root at $1$, the general solution of it has the form

$$\frac{1}{\rho_k} = A + B k + C k^2$$

for suitable chosen constants $A, B, C$. Since $\rho_0 = \rho$ and by construction, $\rho_1 = \rho_{-1}$, we find
$$\frac{1}{\rho_k} = \frac{1}{\rho} + \frac{\rho}{1+\rho}k^2
\quad\iff\quad \rho_k = \frac{\rho}{1 + \frac{\rho^2}{1+\rho} k^2}
$$
If $\rho$ is chosen such that

$$\rho^{2k} \le \rho_k \quad\text{ for all } k \ge 1\tag{*1}$$

then the circles $C_k$ will be large enough to hold a sequences of circles of area 
$1, q, q^2, q^3, q^4, \ldots$ in following order $C_b, C_0, C_{1}, C_{-1}, C_{2}, C_{-2}, \ldots$.

A few plots of $\rho_k - \rho^{2k}$ for various $k$ shows that $(*1)$ is true for small $\rho$. The smallest $\rho$ that cause trouble fails at $k = 1$. This leads to
a determination of the critical value $\rho_c$ as a root of

$$\frac{\rho}{1 + \frac{\rho^2}{1+\rho} } - \rho^2 = 0 \quad\implies\quad \rho^3+\rho^2-1 = 0$$

appeared in the assertion at the beginning of this answer.

Following is a picture showing the circle arrangement at $\rho = 0.75$.

- The pink circle is circle $C_b$.
- The orange circles with label $C_k, k = 0, \pm 1, \pm 2$ isn't circle $C_k$.
  Circle $C_k$ is the blue circle behind it.
- Together with $C_b$, the orange circles are those circles with area $q^k$
  which we want to fit inside the circle with area $a$.

The $\rho = 0.75$ used in this figure is very close to $\rho_c$. As one can see,
circles $C_0, C_1, C_2, \ldots$ get blocked by the corresponding orange circles and nearly
invisible. When we increase $\rho$ beyond $\rho_c$, the orange circle on top of $C_1$ 
grows too large and $C_1$ no longer able to contain it. 
Since $C_1$ is one of the largest circle one can place inside $C_a \setminus ( C_b \cup C_0 )$, $Q(a)$ no longer equal to $(\sqrt{a}-1)^2$.

[image: Circle arrangement at $\rho = 0.75$]

**Part II - Lower bound estimation for large $a$**

Let us switch to case of large $a$ and establish a non-trivial lower bound
for $Q(a)$.
Let $\rho = \sqrt{q}$ once again.

For any $r \ge 3$, let $m = \lfloor \frac{r-1}{2}\rfloor \ge 1$. 
Start with a regular hexagon with side $2m$, we subdivide it into a bunch of equilateral
triangles of side $2$. This give us a hexagonal patch on a triangular lattice with spacing $2$. This patch will contains $3m(m+1)$ faces and $3m(m+1) + 1$ vertices. If we place a circle of unit radius on each of the vertices, the resulting collection of circles can be placed inside a big circle of radius $r$. Since $r \ge 2m+1 > r-2$, we have

$$3m(m+1) + 1 = \frac{3(2m+1)^2+1}{4} > \frac34(r-2)^2$$

This means for any $r \ge 3$, we can pack at least 
$\left\lceil \frac34(r-2)^2 \right\rceil$ unit circles inside a circle of radius $r$.

As a consequence, for any $a > 9a_c$, we can pack at least

$$N = \left\lceil \frac{3a}{4a_c}\left(1 - 2\sqrt{\frac{a_c}{a}}\right)^2 \right\rceil$$

circles of area $a_c$ inside a circle of area $a$.

For any $\rho$ such that $\rho^N \le \rho_c$, let $D_0, D_1, D_2, \ldots$ be a sequence of circles with $\text{Area}(D_k) = q^k = \rho^{2k}$. We can split them into $N$ groups:

$$
\{\;D_0, D_N, D_{2N}, \ldots\;\},
\{\;D_1, D_N+1, D_{2N+1}, \ldots\;\},
\ldots\\
\{\;D_{N-1}, D_{N+(N-1)}, D_{2N+(N-1)}, \ldots\;\}.
$$
Since $\rho^N \le \rho_c$, we can fit each group inside a circle of area $a_c$. 
As a result, we can pack all $D_k$ inside a single circle of area $a$. This establishes
a lower bound for $Q(a)$ as

$$
Q(a) \ge \rho_c^{\frac{2}{N}} \ge \rho_c^{
\frac{8a_c}{3a}\left(1-2\sqrt{\frac{a_c}{a}}\right)^{-2}
}
\sim 1 - \frac{\lambda_\ell}{a} + O\left(a^{-3/2}\right) \tag{*2}
$$
where $\displaystyle\;\lambda_\ell = \frac{8|\log\rho_c|a_c}{3} \approx  2.30928260910042$.

Since the total area of the circles $D_k$ cannot exceed $a$, we find a trivial upper
bound for $Q(a)$

$$\frac{1}{1-Q(a)} \le a \quad\implies\quad Q(a) \le 1 - \frac{1}{a}$$

Compare this with $(*2)$, we find $(*2)$ implies for large $a$, we can cover at
least $\sim 40\%$ of area $a$ by the circles $D_k$. Intuitively, this looks
a little bit too low to me. I believe there is still a huge room of improvement
for the lower bound estimation.

**Update - a more satisfactory lower bound estimate**

After more fooling around, I find above lower bound estimate is indeed far from optimal.

For any integer $n \ge 24$, let

$$\alpha_n = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2(n-\frac12)},\quad
\quad\theta_n = \frac{2\pi}{n-\frac12},
\quad r_n = \frac{\pi}{n}
\quad\text{ and }\quad  z_n = e^{ -(\alpha_n+ i)\theta_n }.$$

Identify the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$. For each $k \in \mathbb{N}$, place a a circle of radius $r_n |z_n|^k$ at the point $z_n^k$. We 
find all these circles lying inside a circle centered at origin with radius $1+r_n$. When
$n \ge 24$, these small circles won't overlap. The ratio of the area
between the circle at $z_n^k$ and $z_n^{k+1}$ are all equal to $e^{-2\alpha_n\theta_n}$.

For $a \ge 75$, if we associate a integer $n$ to it by the formula 
$n = \left\lfloor\pi (\sqrt{a} - 1)\right\rfloor$,
$n$ will be $\ge 24$. Scaling the circle configuration in previous paragraph appropriately,
we get
$$\begin{align}
Q(a) 
& \ge Q\left(\left(\frac{n}{\pi} + 1\right)^2\right) 
= Q\left(\left(\frac{1+r_n}{r_n}\right)^2\right)\\
& \ge e^{-2\alpha_n\theta_n}
= \exp\left[-\frac{2\sqrt{3}\pi}{(n-1/2)^2}\right]
\ge \exp\left[-\frac{1}{\delta_c(\sqrt{a}- k)^2}\right]
\end{align}
\tag{*3}
$$
where $\delta_c = \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}} \approx 0.90689968211711$ is the optimal packing density for tiling the plane with equal circles and $k = 1 + \frac{3}{2\pi}$. 
One consequence of $(*3)$ is

$$\liminf_{a\to\infty} \frac{1}{a(1-Q(a))} \ge \delta_c$$

What this means is in the limit of very large $a$, at least $\sim 90\%$ of the area $a$ can be covered by smaller circles whose radii are in geometric progression.

Comment: I did not check in detail your answer  (yet but coming soon :P), just a minor typo it's Descartes not Descrates.

Comment: @Edwin, thanks. typo fixed.

Comment: @achillehui Great answer, thanks!